# How to implement update () method in DAO using EntityManager (JPA)?

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

What is the standard way to implement simple update?

Example: we have User with phone number NNNNNN and now we want to set it to YYYYYY.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public void update (User transientUser) {
    what should be here?
}
```

User entity is as simple as possible:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column (nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String login;
    private String phone;

    public User () { }

    ... //some setters and getters
}
```

Comment: actually, this is what I have now. But I didn't test it yet due to it's not so easy to configure unit tests' context.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

According to the JPA specifications, `EntityManager#merge()` will return a reference to *another* object than the one passed in when the object was already loaded in the current context. So, I'd rather return the result of the `merge()` and write the `update()` method like this:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public User update (User transientUser) {
    return em.merge(transientUser);
}
```

Then, use it like this (skipping the initialization part):

```
user.setPhone("YYYYYY");
user = dao.update(user);
```

Answer (score 2):

change the property and then use EntityManager merge()

http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29